Internal Transactions Not Indexing
Looking for some assistance with an error on the txs service.
Otherwise healthy system is not showing (indexing) internal transactions.
getting ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8545) error
Running services in local configuration using latest images.

fully synced have configured .env files with RPC_NODE_URL=https://rpc.pulsechain.com

docker-compose.yml has ETHEREUM_NODE_URL=${RPC_NODE_URL} set on txs-worker-indexer:&txs-worker

L2 contracts


It appears the txs-worker-indexer is trying to call a local RPC although above has been configured. Not sure why, (or how to correct) if this is in fact the issue.
Logs show:
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | 2024-12-27 07:03:14,044 [INFO] [754abe2c/index_internal_txs_task] Start indexing of internal txs
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | 2024-12-27 07:03:14,095 [ERROR] [754abe2c/index_internal_txs_task] Task safe_transaction_service.history.tasks.index_internal_txs_task[754abe2c-42a6-47c7-908a-07
855f123c0e] raised unexpected: ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPC
onnection object at 0x7ff88c185970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))"))
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | Traceback (most recent call last):
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 199, in _new_conn
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     sock = connection.create_connection(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     raise err
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     sock.connect(sa)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 586, in connect
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     self._internal_connect(address)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 630, in _internal_connect
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     raise _SocketError(err, strerror(err))
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | Traceback (most recent call last):
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = self._make_request(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 495, in _make_request
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     conn.request(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 441, in request
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     self.endheaders()
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1331, in endheaders
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1091, in _send_output
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     self.send(msg)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1035, in send
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     self.connect()
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 279, in connect
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     self.sock = self._new_conn()
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 214, in _new_conn
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     raise NewConnectionError(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff88c185970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection
 refused
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | Traceback (most recent call last):
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 667, in send
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     resp = conn.urlopen(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in urlopen
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     retries = retries.increment(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 519, in increment
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.conne
ction.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff88c185970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | Traceback (most recent call last):
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 453, in trace_task
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
txs-scheduler-1                      | 2024-12-27 07:03:14,485 [INFO] [???/???] Scheduler: Sending due task Index Safe events (L2) (every 5 seconds) (safe_transaction_service.history.tasks.index_safe_
events_task)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 736, in __protected_call__
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/autoretry.py", line 60, in run
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     ret = task.retry(exc=exc, **retry_kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 736, in retry
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     raise_with_context(exc)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/autoretry.py", line 38, in run
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return task._orig_run(*args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/utils/celery.py", line 59, in wrapper
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/tasks.py", line 196, in index_internal_txs_task
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     ) = InternalTxIndexerProvider().start()
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/indexers/ethereum_indexer.py", line 439, in start
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     current_block_number = self.ethereum_client.current_block_number
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/safe_eth/eth/ethereum_client.py", line 1340, in current_block_number
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return self.w3.eth.block_number
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/eth/eth.py", line 137, in block_number
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return self.get_block_number()
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 75, in caller
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     result = w3.manager.request_blocking(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 329, in request_blocking
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = self._make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 213, in _make_request
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return request_func(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/middleware/cache.py", line 115, in middleware
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/middleware/gas_price_strategy.py", line 101, in middleware
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 126, in middleware
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 126, in middleware
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 126, in middleware
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/middleware/buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 43, in middleware
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 126, in middleware
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = make_request(method, params)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/providers/rpc.py", line 90, in make_request
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     raw_response = make_post_request(
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/_utils/request.py", line 114, in make_post_request
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = get_response_from_post_request(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/_utils/request.py", line 107, in get_response_from_post_request
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     response = session.post(endpoint_uri, *args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in post
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 700, in send
txs-worker-indexer-1                 |     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.co
nnection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff88c185970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | 2024-12-27 07:03:14,540 [INFO] [e13bbb69/index_safe_events_task] Start indexing of Safe events
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | 2024-12-27 07:03:14,684 [INFO] [e13bbb69/index_safe_events_task] Find Safe events processed 0 events
txs-worker-indexer-1                 | 2024-12-27 07:03:14,758 [INFO] [e13bbb69/index_safe_events_task] Task safe_transaction_service.history.tasks.index_safe_events_task[e13bbb69-6008-44e1-9874-1a5ba
4a416ce] succeeded in 0.22191184991970658s: (0, 0)


What software are you using? Was it running at some time? Are the containers correctly configured? Without more details it looks like some service is down, perhaps due to an incorrect configuration.

This is specifically related to gnosis-safe infrastructure.
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md
Using the local deployment on pulsechain id 369.
all services are up and running as you would expect, so this looks to be either a config setting issue in docker-compose or .env files for the services.
all other indexing tasks are working correctly, just the internal transactions not getting displayed in web front end.
I can see all the internal transactions in the django txs interface at /txs/admin/history/internaltx/
